# I can't use my wifi connection in a live environment after restarting

Tags: wireless, live-environment

I am using live mode of Ubuntu 12.04. Every time I activate the additional drivers and restart the system, the wireless connection is still grayed in the options, and the driver is still deactivated.

Comment: System settings made in a live system get lost after reboot

Comment: That's the expected behaviour, what you expected? Maybe you should install Ubuntu instead.

Answer (score 0):

All changes made to a live environment are not persistent. So, if you save anything, install, remove, modify, all changes will be lost as soon as you reboot the system. The only way to keep changes is to install Ubuntu directly to the USB instead.